# calculate the median for aggregated data after groupby

Tags: python, group-by, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataset like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'product_category_name':["food", "drink", "flower", "book", "food", "food", "drink", "flower", "book", "food",],
                 'order_date-time':['2017-09-13 08:59:02', '2017-06-28 11:52:20', '2018-05-18 10:25:53', '2017-08-01 18:38:42', '2017-08-10 21:48:40','2017-07-27 15:11:51',
                                   '2018-03-18 21:00:44','2017-08-05 16:59:05', '2017-08-05 16:59:05','2017-06-05 12:22:19'],
                'delivery_date_time':['2017-09-20 23:43:48', '2017-07-13 20:39:29','2018-06-04 18:34:26','2017-08-09 21:26:33','2017-08-24 20:04:21','2017-08-31 20:19:52',
                                      '2018-03-28 21:57:44','2017-08-14 18:13:03','2017-08-14 18:13:03','2017-06-26 13:52:03']})
```

to calculate the delivery delay for each product I did this:

```
data['order_date-time']=pd.to_datetime(data['order_date-time'])
data['delivery_date_time']=pd.to_datetime(data['delivery_date_time'])
data['delivery delay']= data['delivery_date_time']-data['order_date-time']
```

to calculate the median delivery time and the count for each product category I do this:

```
d=data.groupby(["product_category_name"]).agg({'delivery delay':['median', 'count']})
```

I need to sort the data based on delivery speed and have this output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to edit your example, because it was raising an Exception (`agg` requires a numeric column, but `delivery delay` is a Timedelta).

By the way, after you execute your last line of code, you have to do this:

```py
>>> sorted_d = d.sort_values(('delivery delay', 'median'))
>>> sorted_d
                               delivery delay      
                                       median count
product_category_name                              
book                   8 days 14:00:54.500000     2
drink                 12 days 16:52:04.500000     2
flower                13 days 04:41:15.500000     2
food                  17 days 11:52:42.500000     4
```

Comment: I need to sort data based on delivery speed not median

Comment: There is no delivery speed in your example, nor in your desired output

Comment: data['delivery delay']= data['delivery_date_time']-data['order_date-time'] this is delivery speed, the less delivery speed is the fast delivery is